# Inputs along with characters in C++

Tags: c++, input

I have been trying to write a prog which accepts college fees as input in the form Rs50000 and i would like to use only the integral part for the computation. How can i do that??
Is this possible??

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int fee;
   cin >> Rs >> fee;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you probably have to read the input as a string, check that the first two letters are "Rs" and then separate that, and finally convert the string after "Rs" to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible and there are lots of ways to do what you want, here's one way. 
Take input as a string and remove "Rs" using substr(). Then convert it to int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream stream;
    string amount,str;
    int fee;
    getline (cin, amount);
    str = amount.substr(2);
    stream << str;
    stream >> fee;

    cout << "Fee is : " << fee+1 << "\n"; //fee
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the string and process it as you've described, the following should work.

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
int fee = atoi(input.substr(2).c_str());
```

This code takes input from stdin. Then it parses the fee (3rd character to end) as an int.
There are, of course, other ways to do this. I am a fan of `c_str()` and `atoi()` because of a background in C, however a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is just as capable.

A note on your original code. It may be natural to think that you would stream in twice:
`std::cin >> Rs >> fee;` because one part is a string and the other is an int. However, `std::cin` streams are delimitated by whitespace.

Hope this helps!